# Submenu positioning not under parent item

Tags: html, css

The submenu is not displaying under the parent item, whereas on the left. Tried to take the absolute off, and on, but it does not seem to make any effect.

JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/42qg5/

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About SRJC</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Admission</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">The SR Programmes</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">CCAs</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portals</a>

            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">ASPIRE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Staff & Parents</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu ul li ul li {
   background: #1f2024;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
   border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
   -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
   -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
   -o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
   -ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
   transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated Fiddle with code.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42qg5/1/)**

```
#menu ul li ul { 
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
height: auto;
width: 100px;
background-color: #e13393;
border-bottom: 2px solid #fcc402;
display: none;
z-index: 999;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:30px;
}

#menu li { 
display: inline; 
color: #fff;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't the text appear?

Comment: It's because you gave "opacity:0; and position:absolute;" in "#menu ul li ul li" in css. Remove that. and it will work.